# Python beautifulsoup iframe text extract

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new with Beautifulsoup, I'm trying to extract some raw data from this site, I did the parsing.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
path='https://www.esquire.com/entertainment/tv/g28380481/best-anime-2019/'
f = urlopen(path)
html = str(f.read())
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
txt = soup.find_all('iframe')
```

I got this bs4 object

```
[<iframe allowfullscreen="true" data-src="//www.youtube.com/embed/6M7f41OJfcM?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>,
 <iframe allowfullscreen="true" data-src="//www.youtube.com/embed/0glqBjvku84?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>,
 <iframe allowfullscreen="true" data-src="//www.youtube.com/embed/YKJf876thxw?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>,
 <iframe allowfullscreen="true" data-src="//www.youtube.com/embed/SdFgPGSmy0Y?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>,
 <iframe allowfullscreen="true" data-src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Ie-bo3IulmY?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>,
 <iframe allowfullscreen="true" data-src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ApLudqucq-s?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>,
 <iframe allowfullscreen="true" data-src="//www.youtube.com/embed/FpRk3m3Y-Zg?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>,
 <iframe allowfullscreen="true" data-src="//www.youtube.com/embed/J9tu253SOas?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>,
 <iframe allowfullscreen="true" data-src="//www.youtube.com/embed/lCPf9SA4mgU?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>,
 <iframe allowfullscreen="true" data-src="//www.youtube.com/embed/neqxQdpTyXE?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>]
```

now I'm looking to extract the websites from each element, I've tried with this code below. I would know which Beautifulsoup commands to use instead of replacing each element to a string a doing the search.

```
import re
trailers=[]
pattern='(www.+1)'
for line in txt:
  line=str(line)
  trailers.append(re.search(pattern,line).group(0))

trailers
['www.youtube.com/embed/6M7f41OJfcM?enablejsapi=1',
 'www.youtube.com/embed/0glqBjvku84?enablejsapi=1',
 'www.youtube.com/embed/YKJf876thxw?enablejsapi=1',
 'www.youtube.com/embed/SdFgPGSmy0Y?enablejsapi=1',
 'www.youtube.com/embed/Ie-bo3IulmY?enablejsapi=1',
 'www.youtube.com/embed/ApLudqucq-s?enablejsapi=1',
 'www.youtube.com/embed/FpRk3m3Y-Zg?enablejsapi=1',
 'www.youtube.com/embed/J9tu253SOas?enablejsapi=1',
 'www.youtube.com/embed/lCPf9SA4mgU?enablejsapi=1',
 'www.youtube.com/embed/neqxQdpTyXE?enablejsapi=1']
```

how could I use attributes here to extract names?

```
<span class="listicle-slide-hed-text">Fruits Basket (Funimation)</span>,
<span class="listicle-slide-hed-text">One Punch Man (Hulu)</span>,
<span class="listicle-slide-hed-text">Rilakkuma and Kaoru (Netflix)</span>,
<span class="listicle-slide-hed-text">Mob Psycho 100 II (Crunchyroll)</span>,
<span class="listicle-slide-hed-text">Ride Your Wave (July release at Fantasia Fest)</span>,
<span class="listicle-slide-hed-text">The Promised Neverland (Hulu)</span>,
<span class="listicle-slide-hed-text">Vinland Saga (Amazon Prime)</span>,
<span class="listicle-slide-hed-text">Boogiepop Never Laughs (Crunchyroll)</span>,
<span class="listicle-slide-hed-text">Saga of Tanya the Evil (Crunchyroll)</span>,
<span class="listicle-slide-hed-text">Dororo (Amazon Prime)</span>
```

Comment: Please provided what you have tried and whats your expected output?

Comment: dear Sabri - kunduK is right: we need to have some more insights in what you have done so far - wich endeavours and trials - wich attemts to solve the task and which code - even snippets. You should provide us more than just the wish to work with bs4.  We  look forward to hear from you again

Comment: You can access an element's attributes like a dictionary, e.g., `for i in soup.find_all('iframe'): print(i['data-src'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use regex here.

A much easier way could be to use the `attrs` property of beautifulsoup's elements like:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
path='https://www.esquire.com/entertainment/tv/g28380481/best-anime-2019/'
f = urlopen(path)
html = str(f.read())
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
txt = soup.find_all('iframe')

for element in txt:    
    print(element.attrs["data-src"][2:])
```

Which produces the same results:

```
www.youtube.com/embed/6M7f41OJfcM?enablejsapi=1
www.youtube.com/embed/0glqBjvku84?enablejsapi=1
www.youtube.com/embed/YKJf876thxw?enablejsapi=1
www.youtube.com/embed/SdFgPGSmy0Y?enablejsapi=1
www.youtube.com/embed/Ie-bo3IulmY?enablejsapi=1
www.youtube.com/embed/ApLudqucq-s?enablejsapi=1
www.youtube.com/embed/FpRk3m3Y-Zg?enablejsapi=1
www.youtube.com/embed/J9tu253SOas?enablejsapi=1
www.youtube.com/embed/lCPf9SA4mgU?enablejsapi=1
www.youtube.com/embed/neqxQdpTyXE?enablejsapi=1
```

You can read more about how to process attributes here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes

Comment: what code to use here                                                                                                 <span class="listicle-slide-hed-text">Fruits Basket (Funimation)</span>                          
to extract 'Fruits Basket (Funimation)'